# Detect inline image loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I know there are many ways to detect if images have been loaded the traditional way (i.e. `<img src="bar.jpg"/>`, but is there a way to detect when images are completely loaded inline (as in, `<div class="foo" style="background-image: url(bar.jpg)">`)?

I am uploading images via FilePicker and the image is then set as the background image to the parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window `load` event signifies that all images in the page have been loaded.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

This occurs during the initial load of the page for the resources specified in the HTML of the page.

---

If you are dynamically setting an image to be a background image, there is no event for when that background image has been loaded.  If you wanted to know when that image was loaded, you could load it yourself in an image object and watch the onload handler for that image object and then when loaded, you could set it as the background image.  It would be cached at that point so the background would show immediately.

```
function setBackgroundNotify(imgURL, targetObj, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        targetObj.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imgURL + ")";
        callback();
    };
    img.src = imgURL;
}
```

Comment: Damn, that sucks. I figured as much though...the Internet wasn't built with the dynamic elements in mind. Thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

@jfriend00 is correct.  That answer has the advantage of having no dependence on other libraries.

However, if you are already using jQuery (as the tag on your question suggests), you can achieve the same thing with .on("load",...).

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Note, the .load(...) shortcut has been deprecated, so use .on("load", ...) instead.  This has at least one advantage over window.onload.  It allows queueing of multiple event handlers, whereas an inadvertent reassignment of window.onload will blow your handler away.  Furthermore, in the off chance there are any browser incompatibilities with window.onload, the jQuery solution will likely automagically handle them.

You can (more or less) prove to yourself it is working with a little profiling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Document ready at " + Date.now());
});
$(window).on("load", function() {
  console.log("First window on load at " + Date.now());
});
$(window).on("load", function() {
  console.log("Second window on load at " + Date.now());
});
```

Assuming you've got some div's doing some really expensive background image loading, you should see a noticeable lag in time between document ready and the first window on load.